# Using google maps api in custom widget of ThingsBoard.io

Tags: google-maps, thingsboard

In ThingsBoard.Io you can create your own custom widget and I would like to be able to use the google maps library in it. However i can't get the library to load correctly.

I'm adding "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=ABC" (also adding callback parameter doesn't help) to the resource tab and the error I get back is "Error: TypeError: $ is not a constructor
Line 636 column 31338 of script."

Anyone a solution to alternatively load that google library correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the HTML tab in the widget editor solved the problem:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>
```